# Could not execute JS function

Tags: javascript, php

I am still working on my "mvc/social" php project. Right now I am trying to secure the user input on the state message. I made a PHP and a JavaScript function but the js seems not to be seen when called.

I've tried the same js file with another 'project' and I know it is working. The problem is that I dunno how to reach it! :O

The view file is located into `(project root)/views/afterloginview.php`

The js file is located into `(project root)/public/js/application.js`

In the afterloginview.php I have got the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src ="public/js/application.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id = "form_state" action="" method ="POST">
            <input type="text" name="stato"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Aggiorna Stato"onclick="ok_state();"/>
        </form>
```

Meanwhile into the application.js I have got:

```
var NotAdmitted = /[\|\+=<>()%\*]|(!=)|-{2}/; // 

function ok_state(){
    elem = document.forms[0]["stato"].value;
    if(elem == null || elem.length <= 1 || elem.length > 140){
        alert("Aggiornamento di lunghezza non consentita!Lo stato non verrà aggiornato");
        return false;
    }
    if(NotAdmitted.test(elem)==true){
        alert("Hai usato caratteri non consentiti,impossibile aggiornare!");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

I already tried `../public/js/application.js`
but it does not work neither.

The console gives an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined.

As a user stated the code is working! What's the problem?!?!
Still not working.

Comment: Next time, please make sure your code is well formatted. It's really hard to read it as you posted it

Comment: Try the absolute url of your js file like `http://myhost.com/public/js/application.js`

Comment: Or you can use the relative path `../public/js/application.js`

Comment: How about `src ="/public/js/application.js"`

Comment: What's happen when you click on the submit button? Did the form submit? If yes you should add a preventDefault() in jquery

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/u8bmb0s9/

Comment: I am sorry for the code. So,I should try with localhost/Projectname/public/js/application.js? I am working with xampp right now but it will be online in the next days/weeks. So that the absolute url will not work, right?

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? Does it say that you are trying to call a function that is not defined? Did you check the network tab to see if your file is being loaded? Remember that the path to your JavaScript is relative to the HTML as it gets loaded on the browser, not necessarily your php file. See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: @user3078675 Make the URL parts as a settings values in your PHP or Javascript. Or try to search for any way to detect the the url of the site or the working page.

Comment: I've tried the suggested codes but still does not seems to go. How can I check if the file is loaded?

Comment: on your page, in the console, type "document.forms[0]["stato"]" and see what it finds. If it finds undefined, look at what the html inspector actually sees as your page structure, because it's possible your HTML source has typos that break it. The source code you gave is not HTML5 for instance (needs `<!doctype html>` at the top, `<input>` elements are not closed, `<script>` doesn't need a type for javascript, etc)

Comment: Noone? :( The console gives an error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. As a user stated the code is working! What's the problem?!?!

Comment: It does not find undefined :( I've also closed the <input> and added the <!doctype etc...

Comment: YES!
I have changed the elem = document.forms[0]["stato"].value;  into elem = document.getElementById('stato').value

AND IT IS WORKING :D

Comment: Make sure you don't have any other forms in your page, but I'd recommend the "getElementById" approach.

Answer (score 0):

in php you can use the function getcwd() (get current working directory) to make your paths. (despite making MVC should mean you have a better way to manage your paths)

> The view file is located into (project root)/views/afterloginview.php
>   getcwd() will return (project root)/views/
>   The js file is located into (project root)/public/js/application.js
>   so we want to go back in the parent folder, the project root. 
>   put this in your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src ="<?php echo getcwd(); ?>../public/js/application.js"> </script>
```

or you can set a php var like $rootfolder in your model , and manage it in the views.
enjoy!